# angular 2 router 3.3.0 child route

Tags: angular

in the previous router
in router link we just use this for child router

```
<a routerLink="/store/branches" routerLinkActive="active">Branches</a>
```

but for now we create a module the push it as forchild

```
RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

so how do we go to `localhost/store/branches` ?
cause i keep getting an error saying that

```
cannot set property of 'name' unknown
```

this is my store.routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',  component: StoreComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: BranchesComponent },
            { path: 'branches', component: BranchesComponent },
            { path: 'report', component: ReportSalesByTenantComponent }
        ]
     },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class storeRoutingModule {}
```

store.module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    storeRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    storeComponent,
    BranchesComponent,
    ReportSalesByTenantComponent
  ]
})
export class storeModule { }
```

app.routing.module this is my main routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'MainMenu',  component: MenuComponent},
  {
    path: 'store',
    loadChildren: 'app/MainMenu/store/store.module#storeModule',
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

and this is my module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    storeModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    MenuComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: it looks like error is not in routing, error is in some another file. please check stack trace to check file from which error is coming

Comment: Can you include your main routing module and show how you are navigating to this route?

Comment: Try with RouterModule.forRoot(routes). Hope this will work.

Comment: i update my code please see thanks, @ranakrunal9 how do u check with stack trace?

Comment: in browser console you will get full error and stack trace

Comment: no for me when i press the link its just say that cannot set property of 'name' unknown just that